# Unit test keep running in Test Explorer even after Timeout exceeded

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, xunit.net

I want to use Timeout feature of XUnit.Net (v1.9.2) in my project. I wrote a simple test such a way that it has to fail. Code as follows:

```
    [Fact(Timeout=10)]
    public void IsTimeoutAttributeUsefulPass()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20);

        // Assert
        Assert.True(true);
    }
```

I tried to run this test from TestExplorer of Visual Studio 2013 Professional. This test never ends in Test Explorer. This test should fail according to xUnit.Net documentation after Timeout period is elapsed.

I tried running the same test using Resharper and test fails as expected.

I was wondering what is the reason behind failure of TestExplorer to execute test with Timeout parameter because everybody does not have access to Resharper.

Comment: I filed an issue at https://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9934

Comment: @robi-y xunit is not on CodePlex anymore - suggest logging on GitHub if you expect a response. Also, suggest teaching others to fish vs fishing for them :)

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/199

Comment: What version of the Visual Studio runner are you using?

Comment: i am using Visual Studio 2013 professional. i am using xUnit.net runner v0.99.8

Comment: The bug has been reported. You can see/follow this bug is here https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit/issues/28#issuecomment-63847863